# API for Viewing Payroll Data

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

new to IPP.  Wondering if there is a method to VIEW Payroll data.  In tinkering with the API Explorer, I see there is a PayrollItem API with a promising description, but when I try the 'retrieve all', it just returns payroll categories like 'Salary', 'Overtime', etc...  I want to pull payroll information by employee for a specific time period.  Is that possible and if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use the filter endpoint of PayrollItem entity.
Date filter is available(all filter attributes are documented in the following link).

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/payrollitem#Retrieving_PayrollItems_Using_a_Query_Filter

It is not possible to filter by customerID in V2.

If it answers your question, then plz feel free to 
      [Accept the
answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I guess I'm confused.  Would you expect to have your payroll information for each employee to return when you do the 'Retrieve All' endpoint?   I'm not, I'm just getting the payroll categories. Not actual payroll data.  I can use the filter to get the same information (essentially categories) filtered down, but that's the not data that I want to retrieve.  I want to retrieve an employees actual payroll data, their wages, salary, commissions, etc...   I cannot seem to pull that information?

Comment: Yes In V2, it is not possible to filter response by customer ID(as that id is not part of the response body).

Comment: So are you telling me that I cannot retrieve actual payroll data?